# What does "inspire emulation" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I know two meanings of the word "emulation": 1) 'imitation' and 2) 'rivalry'. In the following excerpt, it seems to mean the former, but I do not understand what is meant by "inspire emulation".

> However, there are in the literature of teleology other examples of
>   final cause that appear to be actual or particular beings and not
>   types. Exemplary individuals are said to **inspire emulation** and thus to
>   bring about imitations of themselves (thus Aristotle’s conception of
>   God as final cause of cosmic order).

Comment: What does "inspire" mean??

Comment: (And what does the phrase beginning "and thus" mean?)

Comment: @HotLicks, obviously, 'bring about'.

Comment: So what does "bring about immitation" mean?

Comment: @HotLicks - I think you are being to subtle.  To the OP- the answer is in the excerpt itself :  inspire emulation <=> bring about imitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't even know the "rivalry" or "jealousy" definitions, but Merriam Webster and OED tell me that these are obsolete or rare. In the sentence you've presented "exemplary" describes someone who sets a good example for behavior, manner, strategic planning, or anything else, so strongly that others feel compelled to want to achieve the same state by imitating/emulating this person. They are *inspired* to emulate this person.

Answer (score 0):

Plagiarism is the sincerest form of flattery.

Plagiarism has a negative connotation; but, emulation, much less so.

To inspire emulation is a rather sarcastic way of implying something similar.

Students are often encouraged after reading a particular piece of literature or admiring artwork, to try their skills to create something similar. The great works inspire emulation (to be great, admired, cherished, yet original.)

Answer (score 0):

Exemplary individuals are said to **spawn** imitations of themselves.

> to produce or give rise to

[TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/spawn)